# How to create new variables using counters?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Below is my code snippet,

```
counters=1
details='AAA BBB CCC'
details_$counters=$details
echo $details_1
```

Result expected

```
AAA BBB CCC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval` for variable name interpolation.

```
x="1"
eval "y_$x='hello world'"
echo $y_1 # outputs "hello world"
```

Comment: counters="1"
details="aaaaaaaa bbbbbbb cccccccc"
eval "details_$counters=$details"
echo $details_1
#result : ./aa.sh: line 8: bbbbbbb: command not found

Comment: @Anup try with proper quotation : `counters="1" details="aaaaaaaa bbbbbbb cccccccc" eval "details_$counters='$details'" echo $details_1 `

Comment: @Anup here, if `$details` is not single-quoted inside the `details_$counters='$details'` part of the eval, it will be expanded twice : once because of the double quote, and once during the eval. Adding the single quotes prevents that and gives the expected result

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now i have got the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Use `declare`; it is safer than `eval` (but not completely safe) because it limits the amount of arbitrary code that you can run.

```
declare "details_$counters=$details"
```

Or, you can simply use an array:

```
all_details[$counters]=$details
```